# Как подключить php скрипт?

Tags: php, html

Как настроить сервер Apache, так чтобы в HTML страничках при подключении `<?php include_once tratata.php?>` скрипт сразу выполнялся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без "вкраплений" никак. Минимально можно так:

```
<?php require 'file.php'; ?>
```

Comment: А как выполнить скрипт при загрузке страницы?

Comment: он сам выполнится. Это же php

Comment: @N.Turshiev получилось?

Comment: Объясню, у меня есть таблицы в бд и мне нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы они появились, согласно вашему совету, я подключаю php к странице и он начинает их формировать посредством echo или print ? Верно?

Comment: @N.Turshiev Ну смотря какой у вас код там php. Но вообще да. И?

Comment: Я сейчас не имею возможности опробовать, далеко отправлено рабочего места. Завтра отпиши

Comment: @N.Turshiev Ну давай. До завтра. Буду ждать.

Comment: Ихмо, надо было написать, что в фале лежит.

Answer (score 2):

**В PHP существует несколько функции для подключения файлов:**

- include – включает и выполняет указанный файл, если не находит –
  выдаёт предупреждение E_WARNING;
- include_once – аналогично функции выше, но включает файл 1 раз при
  вызове;
- require – включает и выполняет указанный файл, если не находит –
  выдаёт фатальную ошибку E_ERROR;
- require_once – аналогично функции выше, но включает файл 1 раз при
  вызове;

Например:

file1.php

```
<?php

$fruit= 'яблоки';

?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php

include 'file1.php';

echo "Я люблю $fruit!";

?>
```

Вывод в file2.php будет следующим: Я люблю яблоки!

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос в принципе адекватен и ответ без вкраплений кода в корни не верен. Если есть желание можно из js вставлять генерируя его на лету в пыхе через другой js, но это глупо. По этому придумали шаблонизаторы.
Я лично использую twig.

> http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Они позволяют сделать код более читабельным и изолировать от основной части кода.
Кроме того по поводу этого есть информация в документации.

> http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

В качестве альтернативы советую использовать короткий синтаксис. Правда он немного раздражает.